# Pass parameters by name to BigQuery stored procedure or function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery we usually pass parameters to stored procedures and functions by position something like this:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION FullName(firstName STRING, lastName STRING) 
RETURNS STRING 
AS(
  firstName || ' ' || lastName
);

SELECT FullName("Fred", "Flintstone")
```

I would like to be able to not care about the position of the parameters when calling the function or stored procedure. Perhaps with something like this:

```
# This does not work
SELECT FullName("Flintstone" AS lastName, "Fred" AS firstName)
```

Unfortunately, this results in a syntax error. I have also tried a few other possibilities such as `FullName(lastname="Flintstone", firstName="Fred")`, etc and tried to search in the docs but came up blank.

Is there a mechanism for passing parameters by name in an arbitrary order like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close (I think) - Use below

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION FullName(name ANY TYPE) 
RETURNS STRING 
AS(
  name.firstName || ' ' || name.lastName
);
SELECT 
  FullName(STRUCT("Fred" AS firstName, "Flintstone" AS lastName)),
  FullName(STRUCT("Flintstone" AS lastName, "Fred" AS firstName))
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Nice workaround)