# Call BigQuery Stored Procedure by naming parameters

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery stored procedure that is defined like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_name(
    param_1 INT64,
    param_2 INT64,
    param_3 DATE
)
BEGIN
//CODE
END
```

When I call the procedure by doing something like this, I have no issues:

```
CALL proc_name(1,1,'2022-11-23')
```

However, I'd like to be able to call it by naming the parameters as I can't always ensure the order they are passed through in is the same order they are declared, for example:

```
CALL proc_name(
  param_2 = 10
  param_3 = '2022-11-23'
  param_1 = 5
)
```

I've tried the above and had no success - `Query error: Unrecognized name: param_2 at [2:3]`

Is there a way of doing what I want?

Comment: Named parameter is not supported in BigQuery. you'd better consider a workaround which Mikhail explains nicely here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73415094/pass-parameters-by-name-to-bigquery-stored-procedure-or-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it is possible. According to [documentation about procedure calling](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#call) the syntax should follow:

```
CALL procedure_name (procedure_argument[, …])
```

So, at this moment I don't see any permissive ways to use the argument names explicitly in the procedure call.